# NSUserDefault - Not Able to fetch value

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, nsuserdefaults

In `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` Method of tableView , I am saving some data in `NSUserDefault` like this

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[storeData setObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text forKey:@"tpName"];
```

and at another place I am fetching this data with this code ,

```
NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSLog(@"tpName is %@",[storeData valueForKey:@"tpName"]);
```

But In this `NSLog` I am getting `null` value . Can Anyone suggest me where am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Where is the other place you're fetching from?

Comment: Use `objectForKey:`, not `valueForKey:`. Also make sure that `selectedCell` is non-nil as well as `selectedCell.textLabel.text`.

Comment: I checked NSLog at didSelectRowAtIndexPath .. the value fetching from the selectedCell is null

Comment: other place is the another class

Comment: @Jean-LucGodard If the value from `selectedCell` is nil then you know the problem isn't with `NSUserDefaults`. You are writing a `nil` value therefore you get back a `nil` value. Now you need to figure out why `selectedCell` is nil.

Comment: @rmaddy .. Yes Correct you are .. it is not problem with NSUserDefault ..

Answer (score 0):

The `NSUserDefaults` doesn't get written out to disk until it gets synchronized. The user defaults get synchronized automatically at periodic intervals, or you can call it manually like so:

```
UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
NSUserDefaults *storeData=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[storeData setObject:selectedCell.textLabel.text forKey:@"tpName"];
[storeData synchronize];
```

If you are quitting your application shortly after the user defaults get set (without synchronizing manually), your `standardDefaults` will not be updated on disk.

Comment: This not true. You do not need to call `synchronize`. It's in memory immediately and on disk eventually.

Comment: The updated answer is now true. Except it has nothing to do with the problem.

Comment: @rmaddy key word is "eventually." When I'm testing user defaults in my own applications, I usually set the default, then re-launch to make sure my app is working like it's supposed to. If I don't call `synchronize` right away, then my app doesn't work as expected (which might be what's happening here). I've updated my answer to clarify.

Comment: Yes, see my previous comment.

Comment: In my defense, I posted this answer before the OP reported that `selectedCell` was getting set as `nil`, and his question mentions `NSUserDefaults` specifically.